# Go back and forth between tkinter windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently struggling to create a tkinter Project which includes several Windows. All I want is to go forward regularly through my program and backwards step by step. After a lot of research I am struggling to find an example explaining how to do it.

I tried to create a minimal example following several posts but it isn't working yet and I don't really understand what I am doing to be honest.

My biggest reference is this post here but it's quite long and complex:
[tkinter - Going Back and Forth Between Frames Using Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616411/tkinter-going-back-and-forth-between-frames-using-buttons)

This example here on the other hand isn't quite enough for me to get it. Both combined and explained might do the trick already:
[Tkinter open and close Toplevel windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56382975/tkinter-open-and-close-toplevel-windows)

- Can you help me create a minimal example (with or without the code for the actual window)?
- And explain what is going on. I assume it's simple so explanations can be fairly short I guess. (If you know of a tutorial site explaining it well I would be happy as well)

Thanks in advance, hopefully we can create a helpful resource for me and others.

```
 def Forward(self):    
        # Open secondary Window
        Secondary_Win = Toplevel()  
        #Close primary Window
        Main_Win.withdraw() #.deiconify() to show again
        Main_Win.destroy()

 def Backward(self):    
        # Close secondary Window
        Secondary_Win.withdraw 
        #Open primary Window
        Main_Win.deiconify()
```

EDIT: as @stovfl pointed out to clarify: I want to switch between actual Windows not just framees. Sorry for the wording hiccup.

Comment: You have to clarify if you want to switch between `tk.Frame`s inside **one** window, which is usually the main window  or switch between multiple `tk.Toplevel` windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is somewhat close to what you're looking for:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()



class temp_frame:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.secondary_win = None
        self.btn_next = Button(self.master, text="Forward", command=self.Forward)
        self.btn_next.pack()


    def Forward(self):    
        # Open secondary Window
        if not self.secondary_win:
            self.secondary_win = Toplevel()
            back_btn = Button(self.secondary_win, text="Back", command=self.Backward)
            back_btn.pack()
            self.master.withdraw()
        else:
            self.secondary_win.deiconify()
            self.master.withdraw()



    def Backward(self):    
        self.secondary_win.withdraw()
        self.master.deiconify()


temp = temp_frame(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Explanation:

A frame is created with the help of the class `temp_frame`. The frame holds the functions for backwards and forwards, opening a new window when forward is pressed and withdrawing the new window when backwards is pressed. When the new window is withdrawn, the main window is brought forward.

Edit: Revised code to avoid creating a new window everytime "Forward" was pressed.

Comment: Seems pretty much perfect to me, thanks. the `def __init__` naming scheme is just common practice I assume?

Comment: Thank you, yes that's correct: The def __init__ is the constructor of the class and is used to initialize the class variables.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good point! I've now updated my answer, please see my edit.

Comment: @temp123: OK, one pedantic point: This `if not self.secondary_win:` should read `if self.secondary_win is None:`